# Unable to merge dataframe in R using merge() instead it repeats them as--> title.x and title.y

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

Based on merge function logic if I have two dataframes 1. `movies` and 2. `producers`

```
movies <- data.frame(    
     surname = c("Scorsese"),    
     title = c("Super 8"),                
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

producers <- data.frame(   
     surname =  c("Spielberg"),    
     nationality = c("US"),    
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

it gives dataframes as

```
> movies
   surname   title
1 Scorsese Super 8
```

and

```
> producers
    surname nationality
1 Spielberg          US
```

Now based on my requirement I can merge them like this

```
> m1 <- merge(producers, movies, by.x = "surname", by.y = "surname", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

to get the required output as

```
> m1
    surname nationality   title
1  Scorsese        <NA> Super 8
2 Spielberg          US    <NA>
```

Which is fine, and it works, **but when I reapeate this same logic for two dataframes**

```
> df1 = read.csv(r"(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\threeColMethod.txt)", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df2 = read.csv(r"(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\fourColMethod.txt)", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

It reads the data into dataframe as expected

```
> df1
     Name  method  c1_frac 
1    JR1   methodA  10.4757

> df2
     Name  method  c1_frac  c2_frac
1    JR2   methodB  10.4757  0.5242
```

**but when the same merge command is used to merge as expected and seen in above merge**

```
m1 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Name", by.y = "Name", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
```

**I get following output, which is STRANGE**

```
> m1
     Name.x  method.x  c1_frac.x Name.y  method.y  c1_frac.y  c2_frac.y
1    JR1     methodA   10.4757   <NA>    <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
2    <NA>    <NA>      <NA>      JR2     methodB   10.4757    0.5242
```

**INSTEAD OF EXPECTED**

```
> m1
     Name  method  c1_frac  c2_frac.y
1    JR1     methodA   10.4757   <NA> 
2    JR2     methodB   10.4757  0.5242
```

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Did you try just `merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)`? I can't replicate the same results with the output you've provided.

Comment: That's a good point, it the tables don't actually have any overlapping values to merge on, a bind in probably better than a merge.

Comment: @MrFlick ```all.x = TRUE``` and ```all.y = TRUE``` is same as ```all=TRUE``` as already tried up.

Comment: Bun in your example you used `by=` with only one column name but you really want to merge based on Name and method. By default if you leave `by=` off as I did, it will use all overlapping column names which is closer to what you want

Answer (score 1):

We could use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

-output

```
 Name  method c1_frac c2_frac
1  JR1 methodA 10.4757      NA
2  JR2 methodB 10.4757  0.5242
```

---

Or with `powerjoin`

```
library(powerjoin)
power_full_join(df1, df2, by = "Name", conflict = coalesce)
  Name c2_frac  method c1_frac
1  JR1      NA methodA 10.4757
2  JR2  0.5242 methodB 10.4757
```

Comment: Yes, thanks @akrun this works. But still It doesn't answers why the same isn't working for the above problem using merge(). But works for the other.

Comment: @NitishKumarPal with `merge` you are merging by a single column 'Name' whereas there are other columns common in both datasets and thus it gives `.x` and `.y` new columns